# My app crashes When I want to show a contact name and numbers in my app

Tags: android, numbers, contacts, android-contacts

I am a new Android developer and I want to show contact numbers and contact name in a list but when only contact name show app running correctly but when I show with contact numbers then app is crashing I am using custom Adapter  please can any one help me

my contactList activity is following

```
public class ContactList extends Activity {
    ListView lvContacts;
      List<String> listname;  
      List<String> listnumber;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<PhoneList> arr;
    ArrayList<PhoneList> arrnumber;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Cursor c1=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI , null, null, null, null);
            // Let activity manage the cursor
            //startManagingCursor(c1);


            listname = new ArrayList<String>();
            listnumber = new ArrayList<String>();
            c1.moveToFirst();
            while(c1.moveToNext())
            {
                Log.d("fghfh", ""+c1.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                String name=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String  number=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                //System.out.println(".................."+number); 


                 listname.add(name);
                listnumber.add(number);


               // Log.d("Contacts : ",name);//+":"+number);
            }
             Object[] obj=listname.toArray();
             Object[] objnumber=listnumber.toArray();
          //   arrnumber=new ArrayList<PhoneList>();
             arr=new ArrayList<PhoneList>();
             String[] da=new String[obj.length];
             String[] danumber=new String[objnumber.length];

             for(int i=0; i<obj.length; i++)
            {    
                 danumber[i]=(String)objnumber[i];
                 da[i]=(String)obj[i];
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Humayoon    zoom"+obj[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 arr.add(new PhoneList(da[i],danumber[i]));


            }
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
            CustomAdapter adpttt=new CustomAdapter(ContactList.this,R.layout.contacts_list_item,arr);
            listView.setAdapter(adpttt);
}
}
```

My Custom Adapter is following

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhoneList> {
    int inflatr;
    Context ctxt;
    ArrayList<PhoneList> data=new ArrayList<PhoneList>();
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<PhoneList> arr) {

        super(context, resource, arr);
        this.inflatr = resource;
        this.ctxt = context;
        this.data= arr;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        UserHolder holder = null;
         View row = convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctxt).getLayoutInflater();
             row = inflater.inflate(inflatr, parent, false);
             holder = new UserHolder();
             holder.textName=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblName);
             holder.stnumber=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblNumber);
//           holder.btnEdit = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_removePay);
//           row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
             holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();            
        }


         PhoneList dta=data.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Humayoon    zoooommmm"+dta.getNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        for(int i=1; i<=256; i++)
        {
            holder.textName.setText(dta.getName());
        }
        for(int j=1; j<=256; j++)
        {
            holder.textName.setText(dta.getNumber());
        }
//      holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Humayoon    Siddiqueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+dta.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              Intent moreIntent=new Intent(getContext(),ContactList.class);
//              String tName=dta.getName();
//              moreIntent.putExtra("Template",tName);
//              v.getContext().startActivity(moreIntent);
//               // ctxt.startActivity(ctxt,ContactList.class);
//          }
//      });
        return row;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    static class UserHolder {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textAddress;
        TextView textLocation;
        ImageButton btnEdit;
        Button btnDelete;
        TextView stnumber;
        }


}
```

My Phonelist class is following

```
package com.example.sqliteapplication;

    public class PhoneList {
        String name;
        String number;
        public PhoneList(String string,String number) {
            super();
            this.name = string;
            this.number=number;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
            }
        public void setNumber(String number)
        {
            this.number=number;
        }
        public String getNumber()
        {
            return number;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            }



    }
```

error are

```
05-12 11:01:42.434: D/fghfh(2720): -1
05-12 11:01:42.451: E/CursorWindow(2720): Failed to read row 1, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 34 columns.
05-12 11:01:42.452: D/AndroidRuntime(2720): Shutting down VM
05-12 11:01:42.452: W/dalvikvm(2720): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f219a8)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqliteapplication/com.example.sqliteapplication.ContactList}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at com.example.sqliteapplication.ContactList.onCreate(ContactList.java:47)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
05-12 11:01:42.465: E/AndroidRuntime(2720):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post the error log

Comment: please post your logcat..

Comment: there can be some NPE

Comment: i post a logcat error plz tell me the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is for projection in your ContentResolver query You don't have your Number in your query so try :

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID};

        mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=?", new String[] { "1" },
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

Comment: plzz tell as some details about it as you write it  mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=?", new String[] { "1" },
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

Comment: that query is part of my implementation for an app which you can change it to your needs. first parameter is the uri as you declare yourself, second is the columns that you need it's data,third is a where clause which i wanted to get contacts only with numbers and the last is sorting parameter to sort based on Display_Name

Comment: i want to show all contacts numbers in a list then what i do on  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=?" this

Comment: this parameter just tells you that give me all contacts with numbers(where clause is Has_PHONE_NUMBER = 1 , don't give me contacts without numbers), so you can replace it with null and you will have all contacts with or without numbers.

Comment: Many Many Thankxx broo some of your code is helping me Thankx

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you've added a column but the test device still has a database file without that column. **Just uninstall your app** or clear its data to remove the old database file and make your onCreate() recreate the database on the next run.

So kindly **Reinstall the app**